# media query for smartphone (landscape orientation)

Tags: iphone, css, stylesheet, media-queries, landscape

I am developing a smartphone friendly version of a website and I am facing a little problem while working with the media query for the smartphone landscape orientation. For the portrait orientation, I am using the following media query and it's working perfectly fine:

> @media only screen  and (max-width : 320px) { style goes here }

but when i am using this media query for the landscape orientation (taken from css-tricks.com), the styles which I write for the landscape orientation overwrite the styles which I've put in for the desktop version of my website.

> @media only screen  and (min-width : 321px) { style goes here }

This is only happening when I am inserting styles for the landscape orientation, this doesn't happen when I assign styles for the portrait orientation.

P.S I am doing the testing on an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set a max-width for your landscape orientation, this won't overwrite your desktop styles until the width is lower than 800px:

`@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width: 800px) { style goes here }`

The other possibility is to wrap your desktop styles into another query and copy them below your portrait and landscape styles:

```
/* PORTRAIT STYLES */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) { style goes here }
/* LANDSCAPE STYLES */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) { style goes here }
/* DESKTOP STYLES */
@media only screen and (min-width : 800px) { style goes here }
```

Note that the Landscape styles will be used for the Desktop version. Sometimes this is a welcome behaviour.

Comment: great, it's working now! thanks a lot! I was also using media query for tablets (portrait orientation only) so I edited the media query which you've listed above to: @ media only screen and (min-width : 321px) and (max-width: 480px) { style goes here } This is what my media query for tablets is: @ media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) { I hope this isn't a wrong practice?